# how to enforce feature orthogonality in keras

Tags: keras

I am new to Keras and Tensorflow. I want to add a penalty to my categorical cross entropy loss function based on some of the outputs in the network. Specifically, I decompose the outputs of a fully connected layer into 8 partitions want these outputs to be orthogonal. So I append the activations into a list and convert it into a stack by using Keras backend. Here is how I partitioned the activations:

```
for i in range(8):
    x_sub = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,i*128:i*128+128])(x)
    features.append(x_sub)

#convert batch of feature lists in to 8x(128*batch_size) keras tensor
outs.append(Lambda(lambda x:  K.reshape(K.stack(x, axis=0), (8, -1)))(features))
net = Model(inputs=[net.input], outputs=outs)
```

And then I define the loss as follows:

```
def OrthLoss(features):
    W = K.l2_normalize(features, axis=1)
    diff = K.dot(W, K.transpose(W)) - K.eye(8)
    return K.mean(diff)
```

However, this does not seem to converge. Is this a right way to accomplish this? I first tried to enforce the orthogonality as a regularizer on weights but as far as I understand Keras performs regularization on each layer separately and found no way to define a regularizer on multiple weights.

Comment: How do you compile your model? Would it be possible to provide reproducible code?